# "bundle exec" telling me gem not found even though I can see it in my ~/.gem directory

Tags: rubygems, bundle, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, gemfile

I'm using Rails 5.0.1.  When I try and start sidekiq, I'm getting this error ...

```
rails@myproject:~/myproject$ bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log
bundler: command not found: sidekiq
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

However, the gem is already installed, as you can see below

```
rails@myproject:~$ find ~/.gem -name "sidekiq*"
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/cache/sidekiq-5.0.0.gem
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/specifications/sidekiq-5.0.0.gemspec
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/sidekiqctl
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/sidekiq
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/sidekiq.gemspec
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/lib/generators/sidekiq
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/lib/sidekiq.rb
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/lib/sidekiq
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/bin/sidekiqctl
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/bin/sidekiqload
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/bin/sidekiq
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.0.2/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/sidekiq_adapter.rb
```

HOw do I tell "bundle exec" where to find the sidekiq gem?

Comment: have you tried explicitly running `bundle install sidekiq`? 
Also `bundle update` will refresh the gemfile snapshot and could solve the problem.

Comment: I did better than that -- I ran "bundle clean" and then "bundle install --path ~/.gem" .  You can see that the gem is installed based on my info above.

Comment: what does `ruby -e "puts $:" ` output?